# Xcode archive build failing. Signing requires a development team

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, bitrise

Hello I'm trying to troubleshoot my failing .ipa build. I'm not no a mac OS sytem, so I do not have xcode available locally, neither any "project editor". My build is handled on bitrise cloudbuild server. The project is generated by the react-native cli `react-native init dashboardwrapper` (github link can be found in the bottom)

The following error I am getting is: `error: Signing for "dashboardwrapper" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor. (in target 'dashboardwrapper')`

In the bitrise log it does though look like that the team ID have ben set correctly already:

```
ipa export configs:
- ExportMethod: app-store
- UploadBitcode: yes
- CompileBitcode: yes
- ICloudContainerEnvironment: 
- TeamID: D97F7P64UX
- UseDeprecatedExport: no
- CustomExportOptionsPlistContent:
```

To my understanding the error msg is a standard Xcode build error (not bitrise specific). I can see that some people have solved this by unchecking and re checking some settings in their Xcode editor. Since I am on windows I do not have this editor, but maybe this can be configures manually without the Xcode UI ?

I do have a file called: `project.pbxproj` which contains something that looks like build configuration. One thing that i've found is this:

```
/* Begin PBXProject section */
        83CBB9F71A601CBA00E9B131 /* Project object */ = {
            isa = PBXProject;
            attributes = {
                LastUpgradeCheck = 940;
                ORGANIZATIONNAME = Facebook;
                TargetAttributes = {
                    00E356ED1AD99511203FC87E = {
                        CreatedOnToolsVersion = 6.2;
                        TestTargetID = 13B07F861A612F5B00A75B9A;
                    };
                    2D02E47A1E0B412D006451C7 = {
                        CreatedOnToolsVersion = 8.2.1;
                        ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
                    };
                    2D02E48F1E0B4A5D012451C7 = {
                        CreatedOnToolsVersion = 8.2.1;
                        ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;
                        TestTargetID = 2D02E4712E0B4A5D006451C7;
                    };
                };
            };
            buildConfigurationList = 83CBB9FA1A121CBA00E9B192 /* Build configuration list for PBXProject "dashboardwrapper" */;
            compatibilityVersion = "Xcode 3.2";
            developmentRegion = English;
            hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
            knownRegions = (
                en,
                Base,
            );
            mainGroup = 83CBB9F61A601CBA00E9B112;
            productRefGroup = 83CBBA001A601CBA00E9B122 /* Products */;
            projectDirPath = "";
            projectReferences = (
                {
                    ProductGroup = 146834001AC3E56700842450 /* Products */;
                    ProjectRef = 146833FF1AC3E56700842450 /* React.xcodeproj */;
                }, ... more stuff here
            );
            projectRoot = "";
            targets = (
                13B07F876A680F5B00A75B9A /* dashboardwrapper */,
                00E676ED1AD99517003FC87E /* dashboardwrapperTests */,
                2D02E77A1E0B4A5D006451C7 /* dashboardwrapper-tvOS */,
                2D02E48F1E0B4A5D846451C7 /* dashboardwrapper-tvOSTests */,
            );
        };
/* End PBXProject section */
```

I'm not 100% sure that this is where I need to do configuration, but it does look like, and I am not sure how it should end up looking in order to work.

**Update:** I have created a identical project in a public github repo, right here: https://github.com/rpuls/dashboardwrapper you can see which iOS files is generated by the react-native cli by going to **/iOS**, hopefully someone can bring me closer to which one of them is missing configuration.

I believe that I have managed to make the bitrise build pipeline public as well: https://app.bitrise.io/app/0147b9ccaf0fedf6#/builds here the full build logs are available

Comment: Have you created the provisioning profiles required for signing the app? The error seems to indicate that you don't have a team and provisioning profile associated with the build target.

Comment: Hi Yes I do ;) both provisioning profile and .p12 certificate have been uploadded to bitrise. Both are used in the step called "certificate-and-profile-installer" which runs and succeeds prior to the failing __build__ step.

Comment: @RasmusPuls this is how it looks when you set the TeamID in `project.pbxproj`: https://github.com/viktorbenei-demo/flutter-demo/commit/a5534337ef47093ef6ce6fe75b0ba21e2784dd79 If this wouldn't help I'd suggest you to contact bitrise.io support via the onsite chat or email, so they can look into it more thoroughly ;)

Comment: Also a note: if you have this `project.pbxproj` committed into the repository then you can open the project file in Xcode, set the Team in Xcode.app (then do an Archive to see if Xcode has any issues with the project file) then commit & push the change.

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out Xcode has two different Team ID options when you do an Xcode Archive + Export (what the bitrise Xcode Archive step does, it performs an Archive then an Export on it to generate the IPA, same what you do in Xcode.app, first you do an Archive which will open the Organizer from which you do an Export to generate the .ipa).

The bitrise Xcode Archive step has two separate options for these:

- `team_id` which is used during Export ( https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-xcode-archive/blob/c3ea1dc97351e1a5f83528ce4dd2aafda2b06720/step.yml#L77 )
- and `force_team_id` which is used during Archive ( https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-xcode-archive/blob/c3ea1dc97351e1a5f83528ce4dd2aafda2b06720/step.yml#L115 )

Based on your build log ( https://app.bitrise.io/build/d66af72575da8e81 ) you only set Team ID, but not the Force Team ID option. If you set both that should work.

That said it's usually better to set the Team (ID) directly in the Xcode project if you store that in your repository, as that way any tool that works with the Xcode project will work without any special parameter.

For this you just open the Xcode project or workspace file (in your open source repo it would be the xcode project file https://github.com/rpuls/dashboardwrapper/tree/master/ios/dashboardwrapper.xcodeproj ), and in Xcode.app you set the Team in project settings like this:

[image]

Once you do this you should run an Archive in Xcode to be sure there are no other configuration issues in the project, and if that's successful just quit Xcode.app and commit+push the project file changes into the repo.

With this setup all the tools should work out of the box, e.g. https://github.com/bitrise-io/codesigndoc which is prompted on the bitrise.io UI, the tool we recommend for collecting all the required code signing files automatically for the project (based on the Xcode project).

Comment: Thanks for your very thoroughly explanation! I attempted this already. :( You can follow all my different attempts here: https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/ios-error-signing-requires-a-development-team/8602/20 Setting the force team id, semmed to just set off a domino effect of new errors. I am almost giving up trying to succeed a build entirely without a mac computer. Seems like the react native generated project, is not 100% compatible with bitrises' workflow modules (yet) - at least not without using xcode locally for configuration.

Comment: @RasmusPuls If you don't have a Mac computer you can remote desktop into a bitrise build VM by following this guide: https://gist.github.com/viktorbenei/c6d4fe1e68de739dbb5f4f15de76b9db . We're working on built in remote access which should be available soon (in the next month), until that you can use this guide. With this you can Remote Desktop (VNC) into the build VM and so have a GUI view and use that as a mac machine. Note: the step in the guide does not work on Mojave, that will be fixed in the built in remote access option. For now run this on a High Sierra stack e.g. Xcode 10.1 or lower

Comment: The best option is certainly to configure the Xcode project, the one you have in your repo, instead of using these special options like `force_team_id` in specific steps. Once the Xcode project is configured and committed+pushed into the repo things will work as all tools which use Xcode or depend on Xcode will just work without workarounds ;)

Comment: Must say, that is beyond cool! I just installed Mojave on a oracle virtualBox to try to fix it locally. If this does not work, then I am most exited to access your machines with VNC hopefully soon :) Keep up the awesome work !

Comment: Thanks we definitely will! ;) If you'd have any questions let me know!